# To identify the background process & bring to foreground in C++ WIN32

Tags: c++, winapi

Can anyone tell me how to identify a particular background process (i.e., Already running application) and bring to foreground? For example, if a Notepad application is running in the background, when I run my WIN32 application, it should identify the Notepad application and notepad should pop up or come to foreground.

I tried SwitchToThisWindow() function, but it works like Alt+tab. It will not identify the background process.

Pls suggest me walkthrough guide for this..

Thank you..

Comment: Sounds like a job for `EnumWindows` and `SetForegroundWindow`.

Comment: *In a time where a windows system was ravaged by foreground processes, there was one function who fought back.. And its name was `SetForegroundWindow`!*

Comment: Ya, SetForegroundWindow will kepp my window to top. But is there any way to identify the background process ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But is there any way to identify the background process

That's a Unix shell notion, Windows doesn't have it.  Right now I've got 10 "background" processes that have created windows that are not in the foreground, another good 50 or so that have not.  None of them are THE background process, they are all equally backgroundish.  You normally click the taskbar button for a window or press Alt+Tab to switch one of them to the foreground.  Or call SetForegroundWindow() in code.

Comment: I assumed they was after the "background" process of a given window. *nix windows aren't as tightly coupled to a process (as it may be on another machine :)

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear what you mean by 'background process', but here's some ideas:

Use [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) to get you *all* the top-level HWNDs on the desktop. This will include a bunch of stuff you don't want that you'll have to filter out. Recommend you play with Spy++ to see what the HWND tree looks like, and what sort of HWNDs you'll find here:

From this set, you'll want to filter out or ignore invisible HWNDs (use IsWindowVisible or check for the WS_VISIBLE style).

Also filter out windows that have WS_POPUP set - those are things like tooltips, menu popups, floating toolbars, and the like.

To filter out the currently active window, (if you don't already know it) use GetGUIThreadInfo with idThread=0; GUIHREADINFO.hwndActive returns the active window, so any top-level HWND that's not it is an inactive window.

If you're looking specifically for minimized windows, you can detect those using [IsIconic(hwnd)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633527(v=vs.85).aspx).

Finally, when you've found a window that you consider to be 'background', you can use GetWindowText to get the title, or GetWindowThreadProcessId to get the process ID.