# how do I retrieve the information shown in Task Manager?

Tags: winapi

Using Win32 in C++, how can I get the information for currently running processes as shown in Task Manager?

I'm specifically trying to get three pieces of information:

- A list of running processes. I'm currently using [EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to successfully fetch a list of processId values.
- For each processId: whether it would be listed under "Apps" in the "Processes" pane of Task Manager. I'm struggling how to determine that a running process is an "App", and not a "Background Process" or a "Windows process". I'm only interested in those listed under "Apps".
- For each processId: In the "Details" pane, the "Description" of the app

Other SO answers for similarly questions seem to be for C#, and not for C++.

So...to recap: for a given process Id, how do I determine whether Task Manager considers this an "App", and if so, how do I get the "Description" from the processId.

Comment: You should be fetching handles not process Ids

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata How does one fetch handles for all running processes?

Comment: You should call [`OpenProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx) on your Ids

Answer (score 1):

You can get process description information by using [`VerQueryValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winver/nf-winver-verqueryvaluea?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
if you need example of how it works, you can look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/181615/) and find there working and clear code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get process description information by calling [`VerQueryValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647464.aspx)

As for whether you can get *background processes*, you probably can check for `WS_VISIBLE` (best done by calling [`IsWindowsVisible()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) but this does not necessarily mean a process is a background one. See [Han Passant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11010256/612717).